# Execution time of for loop over elements is faster than the inner AJAX call can respond

Tags: javascript

I have function LoadTempMovieList(), and need to load movies from sessionStorage. But it seems that the execution time of the for loop is faster than the AJAX call I'm making can respond, so the order of final output is not correct sometimes. How can I solve this problem?

```
function LoadTempMovieList(){
  var obList = [];
  if(sessionStorage.struct != null){
    alert(sessionStorage.struct);
    obList = sessionStorage.struct.split(",");
    for(var i=0; i<obList.length;i++){
      MovieLoader(obList[i],"movie");
      //it use setTimeOut(), the problem also present 
    }
  }
}
```

update

```
function MovieLoader(name,type,movieArray){
  $.ajax({
    ...
    data:{shortName:name,type:type},
    dataType:'html',
    success:function (html){
      if(html!="0"){
        ...
      }else{
        ...
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: So you need to process each array item sequentially?

Comment: There's no AJAX in that code?

Comment: The speed of the loop is irrelevant. If you make an asynchronous request, the single threadedness of Javascript guarantees that your loop will finish executing before the first callback function starts executing, even if the request has completed.

Comment: Is ajax or something asychronous involved in MovieLoader?

Comment: yes, ajax request is in MovieLoader. I have upload the code.

Comment: What does it mean if `html == 0`? I assume `if(html!="0"){` is the "success" case?

Comment: oh, it's for testing, 0 means cannot get movies.

Comment: Then I think my loop suggestion with recursion will be good. The main thing is that you need to delay loading the next one until the current one ends. If you need to load more than one at a time, you need to tell us that. But I think this does what you want.

Comment: yes, I also think about that way. I think I can store the next action into a queue and start this action after the ajax complex. But I don't know how to develop it.

Comment: @PandaYang I don't know why I didn't get notified that you responded to this post >.< but yes, you can do that. That's effectively what I've demonstrated in my code. Regardless, after each run you're going to have to call some method (recursion: a calls b, b calls a) that keeps track of the array. I've done that. Try modifying your code to incorporate my changes, test, and see if it does what you've asked.

Comment: yes, thank you jcolebrand, it really helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm introducing recursion to load the objects in the order they're in the array. I'm also introducing some code that you may not feel you need to include to verify that we've got an array (in case some errant other function calls this, or whatever)

```
function LoadTempMovieList(){
  var obList = [];
  if(sessionStorage.struct != null){
    alert(sessionStorage.struct);
    obList = sessionStorage.struct.split(",");

    LoadMoviesInOrder(obList);
  }
}

function LoadMoviesInOrder(movies){
  if( Object.prototype.toString.call( movies ) === '[object Array]' ){
    //get the very first object in the array, take it off the array
    var movie = movies.shift();
    MovieLoader(movie,"movie",movies);
  }
}

function MovieLoader(name,type,movieArray){
  $.ajax({
    ...
    data:{shortName:name,type:type},
    dataType:'html',
    success:function (html){
      if(html!="0"){
        ...

        if (movieArray.length) { //test to see if there are more movies left by using truthiness
          //wait 50 ms and call this function again, so that we achieve recursion
          setTimeout(function(){LoadMoviesInOrder(movieArray); }, 50);
        }
      }else{
        ...
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If your ajax call that you refered to in your original question (before someone else edited that out) is asynchronous, then you will have to use the completion function of the ajax call to trigger the next call to MovieLoader.

Since ajax calls take an indeterminate amount of time to complete, it is not completely reliable to try to use some sort of setTimeout() to guess how long an ajax call takes.  The only 100% reliable way to sequence the ajax results is to sequence the ajax calls and not launch the next ajax call until the first one has completed, etc...

You don't show us your actual ajax call so we can't be more specific on the best way to implement this.